# Are skirt suits too formal for business casual?

Tags: dress-code

I'm starting a tech internship next month and the dress code is business casual. I know it varies place to place, but in general are skirt suits too formal for a business casual dress code?

Comment: I used to work at a start-up that was business casual, and the only girl who worked there wore skirts everyday. I don't think it's too formal at all. If you feel comfortable in something else, then go with that.

Comment: @jumper I guess I'm more worried about the jacket being too formal than the skirt.

Comment: Easiest way to find out is to ask your future manager/coworkers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always heard "Dress for the job you want, not the job you have." Go ahead and wear your skirt with jacket too if you want. If you feel like it's not the best after the first day, then maybe go a different route.

You can always ask someone from HR what the best clothing style would be, and they can typically point you in the right direction.

I used to work as an intern with a tech company and I wore a dress shirt everyday for a month. Then one of the boss's told me that I could (and should) wear a t-shirt since it wasn't uptight there as they were all engineers.

Basically wear what you think would be best, and get a feel for the dress code as you continue to work there and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

For a recommended attire of business casual, you could probably wear a skirt suit if you wanted to for the first few days, but I suspect you'll go without the jacket fairly quickly.  In most environments that I work in that are business casual, the skirt suit is normally reserved for client meetings or site visits, and the rest of the time I'll just wear a blouse and slacks or a blouse and a skirt.

Mainly, take cues from the other women in the environment.  Do they wear skirt suits on a daily basis?  If they don't, then you probably can deduce that it's a bit formal.